# NGINX proxy pass to React App not working

Tags: reactjs, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I want to run the following projects using NGINX under a single subdomain: http://localhost:3000 (Loopback API) and http://localhost:3006 (React Application)

Both applications are running under PM2. React App is running in production (using its generated build) with the command: 'pm2 serve build 3006'.

/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

```
server {
listen 80;

server_name subdomain.domain.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3006;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    try_files $uri /index.html;
}

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Loopback project under location /api es working perfectly. The issue is with my React project under my / route. When I enter to subdomain.domain.com I just get a blank page. In the developer console I'm getting the following errors:

[image: Console log]

Using http://localhost:3006 to access my React App works perfectly fine with no console issues so I'm totally sure it is something related with nginx.

I have been investigating a lot about the incorrect MIME type being loaded, but my /etc/nginx/nginx.conf is already running with the following configuration:

```
http {
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
}
```

I would really appreciate your help, thanks.

Comment: On the proxy pass you don't need to use try_files.

Comment: Hello I am facing same issue. Did you get the solution?

Comment: Does anyone has solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

Are you using Create React App? By default, its build script assumes the app is going to be served in the root directory. To correctly serve React under a subdirectory, you need to specify homepage in your `package.json` file.

```
"homepage" : "http://example.com/your-subdirectory"
```

Additionally, you'll want to modify `server/app.js` to reflect this change.

```
app.use('/your-subdirectory/api', require('./api'));
```

Lastly, and most importantly, you'll want to set a basename for React Router as well.

```
  const Routes = () => {
     return (
        <Router basename={'/your-subdirectory'}>
        <div>
           <Route exact path={`/`}component={App} />
        </div>
       </Router>
     )
   };
```

Comment: After doing above changes still facing the same issue

Comment: It worked for me! Step 2 is unneccesary if you add a trailing slash to the host you are `proxy_pass`ing to.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to use pm2 since they are static files and **nginx** is able to serve it by itself.

You just have to let **nginx** know where the files are.

```
server {
   listen 80;


   root /home/user/app/buld <--- LOCATION_OF_YOUR_BUILD
   index index.html
   server_name subdomain.domain.com;

   location / {
      try_files $uri /index.html
    }

   location /api {
      proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to acomplished the same using pm2, I would like to have the monitoring features of PM2 and the ability to stop and restart the app